# How to send notification to all clients using WCF,Iobservable and iobserver

Tags: wpf, wcf, system.reactive

I am using WPF and WCF for client server application. but i got a problem.

How to notify any update of client to other client.

```
Server(WCF)
Client1(WPF)
Client2(WPF)
```

if client1 enter any new record,immediatly notification send to client2 .

please suggest me best way to this complete task.

Thanks..

Comment: Are you asking for a push notification service? Using netTcp bindings and callbacks can be done, plus you'll need to know when a user drops and reconnects.

Comment: i am new in this.. I need some example to accomplsh this task..

Comment: How much do you know about WCF? You can google for netTcp bindings and callbacks examples in WCF, there's no big deal.

Comment: i am new in WCF... but i realize that you are showing correct way..

Comment: Consider using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), it is more suitable  for push based notifications.

Comment: Consider using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). Check out the documentation [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs) on how to push notifications to all clients ( what you were asking for)